# maximum call stack size exceeded error... how do I fix?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, local-storage

I'm trying to code a to do list, that take the values from the input form, stores it into an object, pushes the object into an array, stringifies the array, stores it in local storage, retrieves from local storage, and posts it in a table.

i'm getting the error "maximum call stack size exceeded" in reference to the line where I create the object... i'm not entirely sure if I'm doing the part of saving the values from the input fields into the object correctly...help? thank you

```
var table = document.getElementById("tableBody");

toDoArray = [];


function buildTable(){
addToStorage();
var retrievedTaskObject = localStorage.getItem("task");
var parsedObject = JSON.parse(retrievedTaskObject);
var addTheTaskName = parsedObject.taskName;
var addTheTaskDate = parsedObject.taskDate;
  var tableHTML = "";
  for(i=0; i < toDoArray.length; i++){
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cellName = row.insertCell(0);
    var cellDate = row.insertCell(1);
    var cellId = row.insertCell(2);
    var cellCheck = row.insertCell(3);
    cellName.innerHTML= parsedObject[i].name;
    cellDate.innerHTML= parsedObject[i].date;
    cellId.innerHTML = 1 + i;
    var checkStuff = "<input type='checkbox'>";
    tableHTML += checkStuff;

  }
  document.getElementById("tableBody").innerHTML = tableHTML;
}

function submitForm(name,date) {
  var taskObject = {
    name: name,
    date: date,
  };

var addTaskName = document.getElementById("taskName").value;
var addTaskDate = document.getElementById("dateTask").value;
var taskSomething = submitForm(addTaskName,addTaskDate);
  toDoArray.push(taskObject);
  buildTable();
};

function addToStorage(){
  var storedArray = JSON.stringify(toDoArray);
  localStorage.setItem("task",storedArray);}
```

Comment: You are calling `submitForm` from within the function itself (unintentionally, I presume). This is causing the call stack to be exceeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a recursion by calling submitForm method in iself. Since there is no break condition to stop recursion, maximum stack error occurs

```
function submitForm(name,date) {
  var taskObject = {
    name: name,
    date: date,
  };

var addTaskName = document.getElementById("taskName").value;
var addTaskDate = document.getElementById("dateTask").value;
var taskSomething = submitForm(addTaskName,addTaskDate);
  toDoArray.push(taskObject);
  buildTable();
};
```

It should be something like this--

```
function submitForm(name,date) {
    var addTaskName = document.getElementById("taskName").value;
    var addTaskDate = document.getElementById("dateTask").value;
    var taskSomething = getTaskObj(addTaskName,addTaskDate);
      toDoArray.push(taskSomething);
      buildTable();
};

function getTaskObj(taskName,taskData){
var taskObject = {
        name: taskName,
        date: taskData,
      };
 return taskObject;
}
```

Comment: ok, now im getting taskObject is not defined ---- am I putting the wrong thing in toDoArray.push()? should i have submitForm there? im a bit confused on how to take the newly created object with my values from the form, and then push into array...

Comment: You have to push the result of getTaskObj method into array which is taskSomething in the code. Please use upadated code